# How can I automatically merge unnecessary html tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I merge `a` tags with the same url together if they are beside each other. For instance, I am dealing with html that looks similar to this:

```
<div>
    <a href='/url.com'>This is</a><a href='/url.com'> the </a><a href='/url.com'>same link.</a>
    This is not linked but might have some <b>bolding</b> or not.
    <a href='/url.com'>These are</a><a href='/url2.com'> two different links.</a>
</div>
```

Through jQuery, I would like the inside of the div to be:

```
<div>
    <a href='/url.com'>This is the same link.</a>
    This is not linked but might have some <b>bolding</b> or not.
    <a href='/url.com'>These are</a><a href='/url2.com'> two different links.</a>
</div>
```

I can merge tags together by iterating through each pair of `a` tags to see if they share (1) the same link and (2) the same parent, but then I get output like this:

```
<div>
    <a href='/url.com'>This is the same link.These are</a>
    This is not linked but might have some <b>bolding</b> or not.
    <a href='/url2.com'> two different links.</a>
</div>
```

I'm not sure how to realize that there's text in the middle.

EDIT: Here's what I've tried

```
$('a').addClass('linkCheck');
while ($('.linkCheck').length > 0) {
        first_to_check = $('.linkCheck:first');
        first_to_check.removeClass('linkCheck');

        if ($('.linkCheck').length > 0) {
            second_to_check = $('.linkCheck:first');

            replaced = false;
            if (first_to_check.attr('href') == second_to_check.attr('href')) {
                found_first = false;

                old_content_html = $('#divID').html();
                old_content_text = $('#divID').text();

                first_to_check.parent().children().each(function () {
                    if (found_first == true && $(this).get(0) == second_to_check.get(0)) {
                        html = second_to_check.html();
                        second_to_check.remove();
                        first_to_check.html(first_to_check.html() + html);
                        found_first = false;
                        replaced = true;

                        if ($('#divID').text() != old_content_text) {
                            replaced = false;
                            $('#divID').html(old_content_html);
                        }

                        return false;
                    }

                    if ($(this).get(0) == first_to_check.get(0)) {
                        found_first = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        found_first = false;
                    }
                });

            }

            if (replaced == true) {
                first_to_check.addClass('linkCheck');
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: it's just DOM operations. it's all a tree, so find nodes that are the same, then it's just some tree surgery to merge.

Comment: can you show the code for "I can merge tags together by iterating through each pair of a " ?

Comment: Just did... see above

Comment: should fix the source that generates this. Based on first example where the same url exists in  2 places this is going to be ugly

Comment: are you just trying to remove all duplicates but keep the 1st item that the href matches?

Comment: Sort of - the tags are duplicated but the contents inside may be different.

Comment: If only that inbetween text was considered a child of the div.... I wouldn't have this problem

Comment: instead of `children()` need to work with `contents()` which will include the text nodes

Comment: See answer below. You will check use the outerHTML property to get the indexof() in comparison to the document. If document.innerHTML.indexof(element[0].outerHTML)+element[0].outerHTML.length==document.innerHTML.indexof(element[1].outerHTML)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each anchor, see if its next sibling is an anchor with the same href.  If so, append its sibling's `contents()` and remove the sibling.

You'll need to use the DOM `nextSibling` to handle text nodes correctly, because jQuery's `next()` method skips over them.

Repeat as long as duplicate adjacent hrefs are found:

```js
function merge() {
  var merged;
  do {
    merged = false;
    $('a').each(function() {
      var nexta = $(this.nextSibling);
      if (nexta.attr('href') === $(this).attr('href')) {
        $(this).append(nexta.contents());
        merged = true;
        nexta.remove();
      }
    });
  } while (merged);
} //merge

merge();
$('pre').text($('div').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href='/url.com'>This is</a><a href='/url.com'> the </a><a href='/url.com'>same link.</a>
  This is not linked and has <b>bolding</b>.
  <a href='/url.com'>These are</a><a href='/url2.com'> two different links.</a>
  <br>
  <a href='/url.com'>This is</a><a href='/url.com'> the </a><a href='/url.com'>same link.</a>
  This is not linked and does not have bolding.
  <a href='/url.com'>These are</a><a href='/url2.com'> two different links.</a>
</div>
<hr>
Output:
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: take that `<b>` out of text and this won't work..will also include the `<a>` on bottom line

Comment: Thanks, fixed by changing `$(this).next('a')` to `$(this.nextSibling)`.

Comment: might be on to something here +1

Answer (score 0):

It may seem like this will be a simple operation but it won't. The reason being is that the text in the middle is not a node of it's own but instead just the innerHTML of the parent DIV. Basically what you will need to do is get your  tags by tag name, and in order to check if they are adjacent to one another use the following code.

```js
        var linkTags=document.getElementsByTagName("A");

        for(i=0; i<linkTags.length-1; i++){
            j=i+1;
           indexOfI=document.innerHTML.indexOf(linkTags[i].outerHTML);
          lengthOfI=linkTags[i].outerHTML.length;
          indexOfJ=document.innerHTML.indexOf(linkTags[j].outerHTML);
          if(indexOfI+lengthOfI==indexOfJ){
                //ELEMENTS ARE ADJACENT
            
            }else{
              testFlag=true;
              //GET CONTENTS BETWEEN ELEMENTS AS STRING
              var testString=document.innerHTML.substr(indexOfI+lengthOfI, indexOfJ);
                  //TEST CONTENTS FOR WHITESPACE
                 for(k=0; k<testString.length; k++;){
                       if(testString.char(k)!=" " && testString.char(k)!="\n"){
                           //SET FLAG INDICATING NON WHITESPACE CHARACTER FOUND
                           testFlag=false;
                           //SET K TO LOOPS MAX TO BREAK LOOP
                           k=testString.length;
                         }
                   
                   
                   }
              if(testFlag){
                //ELEMENTS ARE ADJACENTWITH WHITESPACE BETWEEN
                }
              
              }
          
          }
```

Of course with this adjacency check you are automatically assured that they are of the same parent as well as there is no way to open or close the parent tags and still remain adjacent in the code.

Comment: *"The reason being is that the text in the middle is not a node of it's own but instead just the innerHTML of the parent DIV"* Technically it is a node, just not a node that jQuery will select with css selectors. it could even be multiple nodes.

Comment: Alright. I guess that makes sense as it can't exist in the DOM without being a node

Answer (score 0):

You can try this... Add a class for which anchors need to be verified. $.each through all of the `<a>` tags. filtering the outstanding items that haven't been verified to see if the href and html() matches. If they match remove them. Then remove the verify class from the item so that on the next each loop the items that have been verified aren't included.

```
$('a').addClass('verify').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    //you can change the html() to text() is you are only worried about match the innerText
    $('a.verify').not(this).filter(function () {
        return ($(this).html() == $this.html() && $(this).attr('href') == $this.attr('href'))
    }).remove();
    $this.removeClass('verify')
});
```